# How to sort this 3D data in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sorting, data-structures

I have the following data:

1. Groups
2. inside every group there are widths
3. and every width has a meter

for example:

```
 Group 1:
|Width|Meters|
--------------
|144  |500   |
--------------
|142  | 450  |

Group 2:
|Width|Meters|
--------------
|140  |500   |
--------------
|156  | 450  |
```

Now i need to create a sorting algorithm which will first pick the Group with greater sum of meters and then sort the width in descending
I am clueless how to store this data ? should it be a dictionary or a 3d array ? or three lists ?
and with the right data structure how can i actually sort it. I am not asking for the full code even if you guide me towards the right path i will find my way .Thanks

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without knowing more about the problem. Dicts are a good starting point for clear and elegant code. If speed is critical, numpy arrays might be useful. I'd say start with nested dicts (a dict contains the groups, each group is itself a dict etc.) and see if it works for you.

Comment: You need to sort only the group with greatest sum or you need to sort the set of group by their sum of meters and then for every group sort the pairs width-meter?

Comment: @MarcoZamboni - the later, need to sort the set of group by the sum , pick up the one with greater sum and then sort the pairs width meters.

Comment: @JussiNurminen anymore information that i can provide? i will look at nested dict.

Comment: @JussiNurminen think of this as one 'for loop' for groups , inside it one 'for loop' for widths in which meters will be used for calculation.
the algorithm should start with the group with highest meters and biggest width hence the sorting.  
Any other info that i can provide to make it better?

Comment: Using dicts sounds fine. You can sort them by value before the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
#                 Width Meters   
data = np.array([[[144, 500],    # Group 1
                  [142, 450]],

                 [[140, 500],    # Group 2
                  [156, 460]]])

# Pick the group with the largest sum of Meters
group_index = np.argmax(data.sum(1)[:,1])
print(f'Group with the largest sum of Meters: Group {group_index + 1}')

result = data[group_index]

# sort by Width in descending order
result = result[np.argsort(result[:,0])[::-1]]
```

Result:

```
array([[156, 460],
       [140, 500]])
```

**EDIT:**

```
data = np.array([[[144, 500],
                  [142, 450],
                  [150, 300]],  

                 [[140, 500],
                  [156, 460],
                  [145, 300]],

                 [[170, 500],
                  [180, 455],
                  [160, 300]]])

# Sort Groups by the sum of Meters
group_inds = np.argsort(data.sum(1)[:, 1])[::-1]
result = data[group_inds]

# Sort by Width in each group
result = result[np.arange(data.shape[0])[:, None], 
                np.argsort(result[..., 0], axis=1)[:,::-1]]
```

Result:

```
array([[[156, 460],
        [145, 300],
        [140, 500]],

       [[180, 455],
        [170, 500],
        [160, 300]],

       [[150, 300],
        [144, 500],
        [142, 450]]])
```

Comment: Thanks.. Can the result be array([[156,460],[140,500]],[[140,500],[156,450]]) ?

Comment: @Jhonty4 yes it can. Actually my original solution was like that. It sorts the groups by largest sum of Meters and then sorts the rows by Width. I will post it later.

Comment: Sorry ,please ignore the above comment.I need to get the full array as result as I need to iterate over it. can the result be:array([[156,460],[140,500]],[[144,500],[142,450]]) ?

Comment: @Jhonty4 ok, done! I used a different example with three groups. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

The sorting algorithm can be simply created with a divide et impera approach.
In fact sorting the groups and sorting the (width, meters) pairs are different problems that we can solve independently.

The choice of the data structure is up to you and depends on what you need; a group could be a list a namedtuple(width, meter) for example or if you need a bit more efficiency a 2d numpy array Nx2.
The container of the various groups could be a list (or a numpy array) if you don't need to name the groups, a list of (name, data) tuple or a dictionary name->data; there's no strict rule and there are advantages and disadvantages for every possibility (for example in a list of (name, data) could be difficult to find efficiently the data knowing the name, but it is very easy, 1 LOC, to sort. While a dictionary provide an excellent way to retrieve data but could be a little more messy to have it sorted).

Here an example of configuration where I use a dictionary name->data for storing the various groups (which won't be sorted!); a list which will contain only the name of the groups in a sorted way; lists of namedtuple for the data.
In this way I can retrieve data easily and if I want to look a the order I can access the list for names and then the dictionary for the data

```py
from collections import namedtuple

GroupData = namedtuple("GroupData", ["Width", "Meters"])

# Container of groups:
groups = {"Group 1": [GroupData(144, 500), GroupData(142, 650)],
          "Group 2": [GroupData(140, 800), GroupData(156, 450)]}

# Sorted list of names of groups
sorted_groups = sorted([name for name in groups], 
                        key=lambda name:sum(data.Meters for data in groups[name]),
                        reverse=True)                       

# Sort each group
for group_data in groups.values():
    group_data.sort(key=lambda data:data.Width, reverse=True)

print(groups)
print(sorted_groups)
```

Comment: Thanks this is great. Can you give any heads up on how to access/iterate through elements in this lists?

Comment: I tried and Was able to fetch the meters of the first width in the biggest group by this : print((groups[sorted_groups[0]][0])[1])